# C++ - SDL2 and OpenGL - Visual Studio error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm learning how to use SDL2 and I'm following LazyFoo's tutorials.

I've downloaded the source code from lesson 50, which teaches how to use OpenGL with SDL2([link to tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/50_SDL_and_opengl_2/index.php)) and tried to execute it, but I got a lot of erros and I don't know what to do!

These are the erros:

```
Error   11  error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals   c:\users\felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\Debug\SDL2 Template1.exe SDL2 Template1
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBegin@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl render(void)" (?render@@YAXXZ)  c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl render(void)" (?render@@YAXXZ)  c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function "bool __cdecl initGL(void)" (?initGL@@YA_NXZ)   c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnd@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl render(void)" (?render@@YAXXZ)    c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetError@0 referenced in function "bool __cdecl initGL(void)" (?initGL@@YA_NXZ)  c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 referenced in function "bool __cdecl initGL(void)" (?initGL@@YA_NXZ)  c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glMatrixMode@4 referenced in function "bool __cdecl initGL(void)" (?initGL@@YA_NXZ)    c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertex2f@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl render(void)" (?render@@YAXXZ)   c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gluErrorString@4 referenced in function "bool __cdecl initGL(void)" (?initGL@@YA_NXZ)    c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\50_SDL_and_opengl_2.obj   SDL2 Template1
Warning 1   warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library    c:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Arquivos\Drawing - Modeling - Coding\Visual Studio 2013\SDL2 Template1\SDL2 Template1\MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) SDL2 Template1
```

I've never used OpenGL, so I have no ideia of what's happening.

What does that means? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a library file, in all probability OpenGL32.lib. If you have that library available, add it to your project.

Check this page, down near the bottom: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318361(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How do I do that? The same way I did with SDL2 librarys? And where can I found OpenGL32.li?

Comment: @Deive_Ex _' And where can I found OpenGL32.li?'_ Where you have previously installed it perhaps?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's the thing: I never installed OpenGL. Wasn't it supposed to, like, be in my machine by default or something?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh, I searched a little and found a folder called "Windows Kits" inside my ProgramsFiles(x86)(the weird thing is that there's two folders called 8.0 and 8.1 even though I'm using Windows 7), there I found another folder called "gl" and it had the lib and include folders and the OpenGL32.lib file. I added them the same way I added the SDL2, and now I don't get any other error, except for the error 10(the gluErrorString thing) and the warning.

Comment: I've been having the same issue...Couldn't find the OpenGL32.lib file anywhere. Thanks for posting that it was in that Windows Kits folder or I would have been lost!